# How to call a constructor to create an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote the following [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00eeaa727b457565):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int){ std::cout << "A(int)" << std::endl; }
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    ~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A[100];
    delete[] a;
}
```

But I wanted to call `A(2)` while constructing the array, not `A()`. I tried this:
`new (2) A[100];`, but the argument `2` is passed to the `operator new[]`. `new A(2)[100];` doesn't work either.

Comment: `A *a = new A[100]{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};`

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: @HappyCoder No reason, I just wanted to understand how arrays work.